# Drawing a transparent circle with Core Graphics

Tags: core-graphics

I am trying to draw a transparent circle on the screen, where the screen has a black background with 0.5 alpha. However my transparent circle is not clearing the black background. How could I do that? If I wanted a transparent rectangle I could use CGContextClearRect(context,rect) and it clears the background. Any ideas for a circle?

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Fill the screen with black 0.5 alpha color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0., 0., 0., 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)));

CGRect circleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);

// Draw a circle with a transparent fill
CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor clearColor].CGColor));
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circleFrame);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: For any drawing Please check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up the path of your circle, then call `CGContextClip()`, then draw your background.